# POST checkbox value to email?

Tags: php, email, checkbox

I have a simple example of check box's which remember what has been selected after the form has been submitted and there is an error.

That part works great... but, I would like to post the resultant 'checked' boxes to my forms mail function.

What I have now only reports if its checked or unchecked I would prefer to have the checked box's 'value' without the unchecked box even registering.

```
<?php

$CB_1 = 'unchecked';
$CB_2 = 'unchecked';
$CB_3 = 'unchecked';
$CB_4 = 'unchecked';
$CB_5 = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

if (isset($_POST['CB_1'])) {$CB_1 = $_POST['CB_1'];
if ($CB_1 == 'item_01') {$CB_1 = 'checked';}
}

if (isset($_POST['CB_2'])) {$CB_2 = $_POST['CB_2'];
if ($CB_2 == 'item_02') {$CB_2 = 'checked';}
}

if (isset($_POST['CB_3'])) {$CB_3 = $_POST['CB_3'];
if ($CB_3 == 'item_03') {$CB_3 = 'checked';}
}

if (isset($_POST['CB_4'])) {$CB_4 = $_POST['CB_4'];
if ($CB_4 == 'item_04') {$CB_4 = 'checked';}
}

if (isset($_POST['CB_5'])) {$CB_5 = $_POST['CB_5'];
if ($CB_5 == 'item_05') {$CB_5 = 'checked';}
}
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$error  = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
    $error .= "E-mail address not valid.";
    }

    } else {

    $error .= "E-mail address is required.";
    }

    if (empty($error)) {

    $from = 'From: '. @TEST .' <'. $email .'>';
    $to = "someone@company.com";
    $subject = "CHECKBOX TEST";
    $content = "

    checkbox selections: 
                        check box 01: $CB_1
                        check box 02: $CB_2
                        check box 03: $CB_3
                        check box 04: $CB_4
                        check box 05: $CB_5

    ";

    $success = mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
    }
    }

?>



<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<?php if (!empty($error)) echo $error ?>

<br><br><br>

e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST {'email'})) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />

<P>

<input type="checkbox" name="CB_1" value="item_01" <?PHP echo $CB_1; ?> /> Item 01 

<input type="checkbox" name="CB_2" value="item_02" <?PHP echo $CB_2; ?> /> Item 02 

<input type="checkbox" name="CB_3" value="item_03" <?PHP echo $CB_3; ?> /> Item 03 

<input type="checkbox" name="CB_4" value="item_04" <?PHP echo $CB_4; ?> /> Item 04 

<input type="checkbox" name="CB_5" value="item_05" <?PHP echo $CB_5; ?> /> Item 05 

<P>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>

</form>
```

Comment: I think the question would be what haven't I tried at this point.

Comment: No offence but a way you can improve your code and make it more clean is  to concatenate all the variable and index names with a integer and put it in a for loop instead of putting all those ifs.

Comment: I agree with @redelman431, that would be a good place to start fixing

Comment: Is it ok in stack overflow to post an answer involving how to clean the code without actually answering the question? I want to be able to show him how to clean it and comments are not good for posting code.

Comment: Okay, If I had a clue as to what you just said I would... It appears someone edited my original post to remove the part that says I'm a clueless Idiot when it comes to PHP.

Comment: redelman431, I would love it but then that's me. If someone can show me what I'm doing wrong even if it doesn't answer the question it still teaches me something.

Comment: I will post it right now

Comment: @redelman431 - That might be better suited for a separate Q&A, in accordance with this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Sorry about that, won't do it in the future

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing but I went back to one of my earlier attempts and I was just messing around when I made a mistake that turned out to be fortuitous because it answered the question I had posted a few hours ago. thanks for all the help from redelman431 and his or her attempt to steer me to cleaner code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for I suppose in the way of an array which I think 'redelman431' was trying to get me to do but it didn't make any sense to me at the time.

I then stumbled onto another array by 'David Bélanger' that for some reason made more sense to me so I used it into my check box's and it works fabulously.

the new problem is that I cant get the check box's that have been checked to remember that if there is an error elsewhere on the page which is a disaster as my final form has a ton of them.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

    #   Default Vars
    $_group_01 = '';
    if(isset($group_01) === TRUE){
    #   Is Array ?
    if(is_array($group_01) === TRUE){
    #   Count
    $c = count($group_01);
    #   Loop
    for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++){
    $_group_01.= (isset($group_01[$i]) === TRUE ? $group_01[$i] : '').($i == ($c-1) ? '' : ($i == $c-2 ? ' and ' : ', '));
    }
    }
    }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$error  = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
    $error .= "E-mail address not valid.";
    }

    } else {

    $error .= "E-mail address is required.";
    }

    if (empty($error)) {

    $from = 'From: '. TEST .' <'. $email .'>';
    $to = "someone@company.com";
    $subject = "CHECKBOX TEST";
    $content = "

checkbox selections: 

Items Checked: $_group_01

    ";

    $success = mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
    }
    }

?>



<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<span style="color: red;"><?php if (!empty($error)) echo $error ?></span>

<br><br><br>

e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST {'email'})) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />



<P>

<input type="checkbox" name="group_01[]" value="Item 01" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['group_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />Item 01

<input type="checkbox" name="group_01[]" value="Item 02" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['group_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />Item 02

<input type="checkbox" name="group_01[]" value="Item 03" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['group_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />Item 03

<input type="checkbox" name="group_01[]" value="Item 04" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['group_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />Item 04

<input type="checkbox" name="group_01[]" value="Item 05" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['group_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />Item 05

<P>



<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>

</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my attempt to make it remember what was checked makes all of that array checked if one is checked so that's a no go.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not necessarily answer the question but a way you could make your code more efficiant is do this.

```
for($i=1; $i<=5;$i++)
{

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& isset($_POST['CB_'.$i]) && $CB_.$i=='item_0'.$i)
     {
        $CB_.$i = $_POST['CB_'.$i];
        $CB_.$i = 'checked';
     }
}
```

If you fix it that way it may also make it easier for us to debug.

Comment: hmmm, I just tried that but it gives me a " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' " when I tried to run it. perhaps I inserted it incorrectly. I just replaced what I had for handling the check box's with your code. is that correct?

Comment: like this? " for($i=1; i<=5;$i++) " it makes wamp just think about it and stop working.

Comment: You also need a $ in the i<=5.

Comment: thanks for trying but I think I'll just have to keep bashing my head against a wall. I just traded my original problem for a bunch of undefined variables and errors. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I found a way to do what I wanted but I'm fairly sure it's not the way someone who has real experience with PHP would do it. Any suggestions?

redelman431, thanks for your suggestion but it was really too advanced for my skill level.

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['item_01'])) {$item_01 = 'Item 01';}
        if(isset($_POST['item_02'])) {$item_02 = 'Item 02';}
        if(isset($_POST['item_03'])) {$item_03 = 'Item 03';}
        if(isset($_POST['item_04'])) {$item_04 = 'Item 04';}
        if(isset($_POST['item_05'])) {$item_05 = 'Item 05';}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$error  = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
    $error .= "E-mail address not valid.";
    }

    } else {

    $error .= "E-mail address is required.";
    }

    if (empty($error)) {

    $from = 'From: '. @TEST .' <'. $email .'>';
    $to = "someone@company.com";
    $subject = "CHECKBOX TEST";
    $content = "

    checkbox selections: 

                        checked box's: $item_01 $item_02 $item_03 $item_04 $item_05





    ";

    $success = mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
    }
    }

?>



<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">

<span style="color: red;"><?php if (!empty($error)) echo $error ?></span>

<br><br><br>

e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST {'email'})) { echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" />

<P>



<input type="checkbox" name="item_01" value="Item 01" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['item_01'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Item 01

<input type="checkbox" name="item_02" value="Item 02" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['item_02'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Item 02

<input type="checkbox" name="item_03" value="Item 03" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['item_03'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Item 03

<input type="checkbox" name="item_04" value="Item 04" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['item_04'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Item 04

<input type="checkbox" name="item_05" value="Item 05" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['item_05'])) { echo 'checked'; } ?> /> Item 05



<P>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>

</form>
```